# Prolog: Create sublist, given two indices

Tags: prolog

Basically, I need to create a predicate of the form sublist(S,M,N,L), where S is a new list formed from the elements of L between index M and index N, inclusive.

Here's where I've gotten:

```
sublist([],_,_,[]).
sublist([],M,N,_) :- (M > N).
sublist(S,M,N,L) :- sublist2(S,M,N,L,-1).
sublist2([H|T],St,En,[H2|T2],Idx) :-
   (Idx2 is Idx + 1,
   St =< Idx2,
   En >= Idx2,
   H = H2,
   sublist2(T,St,En,T2,Idx2);
   Idx2 is Idx + 1,
   sublist2(T,St,En,T2,Idx2)).
```

As with all my prolog problems, I feel I'm making it way more complicated than it should be. I've got the base cases right, but anything else evaluates to false. Any advice for this problem, and just general approach to prolog? I understand the language for the most part, but I can't seem to see the simple solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solutions follow simple outlook. For lists it's recursion. Recursive programming is simple - just imagine you already have your function, following the given interface/requirements, and so you get to use it whenever you feel like it (but better, in the reduced cases).

```
sublist(S,M,N,[_A|B]):- M>0, M<N, sublist(S,M-1,N-1,B).
```

think of it as stating a law of sublists: sublist in a shorter list starts at decreased index.

```
sublist(S,M,N,[A|B]):- 0 is M, M<N, N2 is N-1, S=[A|D], sublist(D,0,N2,B).
```

and,

```
sublist([],0,0,_).
```

it is exclusive in the second index. tweak it. :)

Comment: what does the wildcard in front of the A mean?

Comment: @AdamDuvall If you mean the underscore `_`, it tells prolog to ignore the variable.  You can use just an underscore by itself, but an underscore with a name is more descriptive.

Comment: @Will Ness I got it working inclusively, but it doesn't work if M is initially 0 due to the base case. It doesn't get the element at index N.

Comment: @AdamDuvall it works as is now: `?- sublist(S,0,4,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]).
S = [0, 1, 2, 3] .`  (the tweak is to use `M=<N` instead of `M<N` in two cases, and replace base case with two rules: `sublist([],0,0,[]). sublist([A],0,0,[A|_]).`.) Congrats on reaching 15 rep, you have power to up-vote now! :) ;)

Comment: @WillNess I'm trying now to tweak it so that if `N > length(L)`, rather than evaluating to false, it acts as if `N = length(L)-1`. So, for example, `?- sublist(S,2,100,[0,1,2,3,4]). S = [2,3,4].` I got this working by adding a second predicate, sublist2 and changing the value of N, but I was curious if there's a simpler solution.

Comment: @AdamDuvall I don't think so, no.

Answer (score 1):

There is the possibility to handle indexing in a way similar to more traditional languages:

```
sublist(L, M, N, S) :-
    findall(E, (nth1(I, L, E), I >= M, I =< N), S).
```

or equivalently

```
sublist(L, M, N, S) :-
    findall(E, (between(M, N, I), nth1(I, L, E)), S).
```

nth1/3 is for indexing from 1, otherwise nth0/3 allows C style - start from 0. I've placed the sublist as last argument. It's a common convention in Prolog to place output parameters after input.

Here a (cumbersome) recursive definition

```
sublist(L,M,N,S) :- sublist2(1,L,M,N,S).

sublist2(_,[],_,_,[]).
sublist2(I,[X|Xs],M,N,[X|Ys]) :-
    between(M,N,I),
    J is I + 1,
    !, sublist2(J,Xs,M,N,Ys).
sublist2(I,[_|Xs],M,N,Ys) :-
    J is I + 1,
    sublist2(J,Xs,M,N,Ys).
```